# How can I use Entity Framework to search only the Store not the local data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4.1 and still trying to figure out some of the details. I have a parent(one)-child(many) relationship in the database. The EF object that represents that child has a property that represents the one parent. I explicitly set the child.parentId FK field and then I can do a context.Add(child), followed by a context.SaveChanges() and the child record with the correct parent foreign key shows up in the database. All is good as far as the db is conerned.

However, while the in memory child object gets updated correctly with things like the PK  identity column that parent Property field remains null. I was surprised by this, is this normal? Once the record is created and I come back into the app, the navigation to the parent always works. It just appears that right after the child is created the parent navigation property is not updated.

I was thinking perhaps I could then just search the context for the child I just created  based on the returned PK and get a fully populated child object but it doesn't work. It seems I just get back an identical object. I think it's just searching the local cache and returning the object I already have. I noticed that context.Child.Local seems to be a way to look at just the local view but I didn't see a "store" counterpart.

Comment: Either dispose the context after SaveChanges and create a new instance every time or detach your object after saving

Comment: Kirk's answer solved my immediate problem but it appears from comments that I can't do what I want, although I can just create a new context (even while leaving the current context open) and search that way. Of course, as I learned I have to be very careful with what I do with anything returned from a separate context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the value of the key you should be setting the value of the Navigation Property (& the object reference). For example

```
Child child = GetChildFromSomewhere();
Parent parent = GetParentFromSomewhere();

// Don't do this
child.ParentId = parent.ParentId;

// Use this instead
child.Parent = parent;
```

You shouldn't need to touch the key directly. When you change the association like this, the key will be updated in due course.

If you change the key directly, the object reference is not automatically updated (the context doesn't go to find the appropriate Parent and add the reference, until you save or resync with the database).

If you change the *object*, then the key will be updated when it needs to be. But again, you shouldn't be referring directly to the key.  EF works on object relations, not key-key joins.

Comment: Duh, thanks (insert emoticon for slapping upside the head). I have to unlearn my old habits. At first, when I tried this I got errors on unique key violations for the Parent. I took this to mean that doing child.Parent = parent was inserting a Parent not linking to the existing one. Then I realized, I had the parent object from a separate context than where I was creating the child. So I just did a context.Find(parent.Id) to get the parent in the current context and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your PK will not be correctly set until you create a new Context.  You should dispose and recreate your context after every SaveChange().

Comment: Two comments: One, thanks for tip on disposing after SaveChanges(). I'm keeping track of a context to minimize db roundtrips but I'm not closing/recreating and I didn't think about it until you mentioned it.  
Two, I'm not having a problem with the PK. While I don't know exactly what you mean by "correctly set", EF does an amazing job of letting me work with the (temporary) PK and assign it to related records (which I'm learning I probably don't need to do) and even though the PK isn't "real" prior to the SaveChanges() it does update everything correctly in all related tables after the save.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the child object directly to the parent object's child EntityCollection rather than to the Context ObjectSet? This will also add it to the Context ObjectSet as well so you avoid the issue to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, this would also work like Kirk's suggestion but this particularly piece of code is Child centric so doing it Kirk's way feels a bit cleaner.